# how to place a long paragraph with equations into equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

[image]There have been a few questions already that I have found addressing the issue of embedding text into an equation environment, however I haven't managed to get any f the solutions to work in my case. Most people suggest using \text to isolate the text, but this doesn't format well if I have a long paragraph of text. Can anyone suggest a neater method for this?

My code is as follows:

We are concerned here with the following Cauchy problem for timelike, maximal cylinders

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\newcommand{\fii}{\varphi}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation} \label{CP} \tag{CP}
    \begin{split}
    \text{Given an initial, smoothly immersed curve}\ s\mapsto (\fii_0(s),0) \in M \text{satisfying} \\
    \fii_0(s)=\fii_0(s+1), \text{and a smooth, uniformly timelike vector field}\ X(s)\in T_{(\fii_0(s),0)}M \\
    \text{along the curve, find a time}\ T\in (0,\infty] \text{and a smooth, maximally immersed cylinder} \Sigma \\
    \text{which may be parametrized such that}\ \fii(s,0)=\fii_0(s) \text{and such that}\ X(s)\in T_{(\fii_0(s),0)}\Sigma
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

and here is the output!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @dexteritas how do i make it compilable?

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson Add your `\documentclass{...}` and the required packages for that code snippet and surround it with `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` (see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Comment: @dexteritas thank-you, done that now I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Just write it as text, with the math `$inline$`, and place it in a `\parbox` inside of an `equation` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\newcommand{\fii}{\varphi}
\begin{document}   
\begin{equation} \label{CP} \tag{CP}
  \parbox{4in}{%
    Given an initial, smoothly immersed curve $s\mapsto (\fii_0(s),0) \in M$ satisfying
    $\fii_0(s)=\fii_0(s+1)$, and a smooth, uniformly timelike vector field $X(s)\in  
    T_{(\fii_0(s),0)}M$ along the curve, find a time $T\in (0,\infty]$ and a smooth, 
    maximally immersed cylinder $\Sigma$ which may be parametrized such that 
    $\fii(s,0)=\fii_0(s)$ and such that $X(s)\in T_{(\fii_0(s),0)}\Sigma$%
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]